# Can a prefab of a complete Unity scene be created?

Tags: unity

Can we create a prefab out of a complete unity scene, so that we can instantiate the complete scene like we instantiate gameobjects in unity.

Comment: from what I read on old information here https://answers.unity.com/questions/223782/prefab-of-a-whole-scene.html it says you cannot have prefabs of prefabs even. so assuming you have a prefab in the scene  I'd say no. But Im not sure. Couldn't you just copy the Scene itself. Or reload it fresh with SceneManager?

Comment: @BigTLarrity that changed recently, and new versions of Unity do support nested prefabs.

Comment: It might be better to use a ScriptableObject to store the state of your scene then re-load it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vmRwLYWNRo&feature=youtu.be&t=25m45s  This would allow you to dynamically generate new scenes from code.

Comment: Maybe a Scene Template would be a better option.

Too much nesting of Prefabs can be a bit of a headache from my experience.

Answer (score 6):

1. Create an empty gameobject at the root level of your scene
2. Move all other objects in the scene to be children of that object
3. Drag that object into your assets folder to make it a prefab

Now you have a prefab containing everything in the scene.

Side note: This method may require nested prefabs if you already have prefabs in the scene. This is only supported in 2018.3 or higher. Here's the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/NestedPrefabs.html) on the matter. Also, quoted from [this link](https://unity.com/prefabs):

> The new Prefab workflows, which are available in Unity 2018.3, allow you to split up Prefabs on a granular level. This gives you greater flexibility, increases your productivity and enables you to work confidently without worrying about making time-consuming errors.